# How to keep ndiswrapper configuration after reboot?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, reboot, ndiswrapper

I've been using ndiswrapper on my old wireless card without any problem, until I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10. ndiswrapper is not included by default anymore so I installed it from the Software Center, then I installed the driver using the .inf driver file. The wifi started to work just fine in all the system user accounts (logging in & out was OK) but after reboot, the wireless card just doesn't work (it doesn't list any wireless connection) and I have to open ndiswrapper (GUI) and reinstall the .inf driver to make it work again.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is it a "daemon" process or something that needs to be started after reboot that maybe is not being installed/configured by software center?

Comment: Is ndiswrapper module being loaded when system boots? You can see it via: `lsmod | grep ndiswrapper` If not, just add it to /etc/modules

Answer (score 2):

As heartsmagic says, the solution was to add `ndiswrapper` in a new line of the file /etc/module:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modules
```

Save, close the file and reboot.

After reboot, check that the module was loaded with:

```
lsmod | grep ndiswrapper
```

(this was my own question but I lost that unregistered account).

Answer (score 1):

The open source driver for my Atheros AR5005G (ath5k module) doesn't work for me.  What I did was blacklist the open source driver and the install ndiswrapper.  There is a nice graphical interface called "Windows Wireless Drivers", to be found in the repositories.  Works all fine, but of course when you reboot it's gone.

The solution was found in the [excellent documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper).  You want section 3.7.  On my laptop it works perfectly.  (Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Pa 1510)