# ndiswrapper is not loaded on startup (thus, no wlan)

Tags: networking, 64-bit, wireless, ndiswrapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep ndiswrapper configuration after reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76313/how-to-keep-ndiswrapper-configuration-after-reboot)

Whenever I boot, the ndiswrapper module is not automatically loaded, despite being explicitly added to `/etc/modules`.

In order to get wlan, I have to load ndiswrapper manually, sometimes even twice or more, by doing:

```
sudo modprobe -r ndiswrapper
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Needless to say that ndiswrapper (as well as the loaded windows driver) both work just fine.

So, why is modprobe not loading ndiswrapper correctly? What can I do to fix it? Should I switch to madwifi?

---

Driver in question: [AVM Fritz!Box WLAN](http://www.avm.de/en/Produkte/FRITZBox/FRITZ_Box_Fon_WLAN/index.php).