# How to fix “Module ndiswrapper not found"

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, 12.10, ndiswrapper

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and whenever I run `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`, I get the following error.

```
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.
```

The command `dkms status` returns with...

```
ndiswrapper, 1.57, 3.2.0-32-generic, i686: installed
```

When I run `ndiswrapper -v` I am returned with this...

```
jason@jason:~$ ndiswrapper -v
utils version: '1.9', utils version needed by module: '1.9'
module details:
filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/ndiswrapper.ko
version:        1.58rc1
vermagic:       3.5.0-18-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686
```

I have installed `commons`, `utils-1.9`, `dkms`, `source` but it's still returning this error. How do I fix this?

Comment: please post output of `dkms status` to check whether the ndiswrapper module has been built...

Comment: Done and posted

Comment: what wifi card are you trying to get running? can you post the output of "lspci | grep Network"

Comment: Note that this seems to already have been asked and answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132894/how-to-fix-ndiswrapper-not-found

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that. Whenever I get to `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` it returns with `FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found`, using both ways.

Comment: @Sam I'm using a USB wireless connector, not a wifi card per say. Specifically, it is a NetGear WG111U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for this error is bug in `ndiswrapper 1.57` version. Check out [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/+bug/1023645).

Download `ndiswrapper 1.58` rc build [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/) with better code than 1.57.
 It will work.
Good luck

Comment: I followed the instructions and it built and installed correctly. However, now whenever I run `modprobe ndiswrapper`, I get no response from the terminal. It just acts like it is loading something, but nothing comes up.

Comment: When you issue a command and there is no response, it means, roughly, 'command executed as requested and there are no warnings or errors to report.' That's the expected behavior.

Comment: Well, what happens when it doesn't return with this `jason@jason:~$`? Because that is what is happening.

Comment: I see, it hangs and never returns to the command prompt. I'd open a terminal and do:  sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog. Open a second terminal and do sudo modprobe ndiswrapper. See what messages appear in the first. I suspect you have a version mismatch. I suggest you go into Synaptic and remove everything ndiswrapper. Then go to your terminal again and cd Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1 (or wherever you downloaded it) and then sudo su, make clean, make, make install. Now can you modprobe ndiswrapper?

Comment: I did as you say and created the two terminals, however whenever I run `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` no messages return when I run `modprobe ndiswrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have installed, this may seem silly, but have you installed `ndiswrapper-dkms`? That should allow you to `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`.

Comment: Yes, I installed it already. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run `echo ndiswrapper >> /etc/modules`

Comment: This should be run as root, or with `sudo tee`.

Comment: Oh yeah, (I had ran _sudo -i_)

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Run this first:

```
sudo rm -f /lib/modules/3.5.0-*-generic/updates/dkms/ndiswrapper.ko
```

Then run this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ndiswrapper-dkms ndiswrapper-source
```

This will recompile the ndiswrapper so that it will work on your kernel. See if it works for you.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Edited my post. See if that will work :)

Comment: Returned with an error that was caused from nothing having ndiswrapper 1.58. Will redo it all see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the right kernel version for 12.10 (check current running kernel with `uname -r` command). Try:

```
sudo dkms build -m ndiswrapper -v 1.57
sudo dkms install -m ndiswrapper -v 1.57
```

Let us know if that succeeds in forcing ndiswrapper to be rebuilt.

Comment: The console returned when I tried either code with this `make KERNELRELEASE=3.5.0-18-generic KVERS=3.5.0-18-generic.......(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.5.0-18-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.57/build/make.log for more information.`

Comment: The make.log can be found in my question.

Comment: So we have a winner: [LP Bug #1023645](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/+bug/1023645)

Answer (score -1):

You can either wait for a fix to [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/+bug/1023645) or follow steps outlined in the bug comments, something along these lines:

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ndiswrapper/testing/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1.tar.gz
tar -xvf ndiswrapper-1.58rc1.tar.gz
cd ndiswrapper-1.58rc1
make
sudo make install
```