# Install NDiSWrapper in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, software-installation, ndiswrapper

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and want to install NDISWrapper in it. I have `ndiswrapper-1.63.tar.gz` downloaded and extracted and gone through the install file in it but I am unable to understand it as there is not much explanation .Please help me the link for the package:-https://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/files/latest/download  .

Comment: `ndiswrapper` is obsolete and won't help you. A better idea is to ask about a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download from sourceforge.net. You can simply use:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

You can read full instructions [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-ndiswrapper-wpa_supplicant-howto/).

Comment: Thanks I tried the first and second step to install the driver but the third step which is  ```sudo modprobe ndiswrapper```   gave me this ```modprobe: FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic``` what to do now? @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @PiyushMhatre The third step is `sudo ndiswrapper -i driver-name.inf` so you are missing the driver name. Do you know the driver you want to install?

Comment: Yeah I have done this command and installed the driver after there is command ```ndiswrapper -l``` which gave me this ```rtbth : driver installed
 device (1814:3298) present (alternate driver: rtbth)
``` and the third command ```sudo modprobe ndiswrapper``` gave me this output ```modprobe: FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic
```. I am talking about the last command's output. @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @PiyushMhatre See if solution is found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/213360/how-to-fix-module-ndiswrapper-not-found

Comment: I have readed that and installed ndiswrapper package from synaptic package manager but there is a same problem please do some help from your side @WinEunuuchs2Unix.

Comment: @PiyushMhatre I have used `ndiswrapper` about four or five years ago in Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04 and never had a problem. I use only native drivers now and have no need for it anymore so can't even test it on my machines. As @Pilot6 mentioned in comment maybe you don't even need to use a non-native driver. What exactly do you need a driver for? I think it's Real Tek Blue Tooth or something like that from your driver name but am not exactly sure what?

Comment: @PiyushMhatre is there any update on this?

Comment: Installing driver using ndiswrapper didn't worked for me because of curroupted hardware . @Kubuntuer82