# struct kernel_stat has no member named cpustat

Tags: 12.10, troubleshooting, ndiswrapper

I am trying to get my dlink dwa 130 wireless usb stick working on my new install of Linux 12.10. From reading online (I know very little about Linux, I use red hat at work occasionally) it seemed I should install ndiswrapper.

I kept getting the error "module not found", and while following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132894/how-to-fix-ndiswrapper-not-found) I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/src/modules/ndiswrapper/ndis.c:2657:24: error: ‘struct kernel_stat’ has no member named ‘cpustat’
/usr/src/modules/ndiswrapper/ndis.c:2658:31: error: ‘struct kernel_stat’ has no member named ‘cpustat’
/usr/src/modules/ndiswrapper/ndis.c:2659:17: error: ‘struct kernel_stat’ has no member named ‘cpustat’
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/modules/ndiswrapper/ndis.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/src/modules/ndiswrapper] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-21-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

How do I fix this? As I said, I do not know much about linux, I am a wondows user primarily.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug with version you are using, check the solution here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12200453

Comment: I reviewed that thread already, but I did not find any helpful information related to my error.

Comment: My mistake, there is some information at the end of the thread, I will try and get 1.58rc1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.