# FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found

Tags: ndiswrapper

I tried all fixes on  [How to fix "ndiswrapper not found"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132894/how-to-fix-ndiswrapper-not-found)

On [answer 3 Fix suggestion #2](https://askubuntu.com/a/133885/212399) : when `sudo make` I get

```
Cannot find kernel build files in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.7.0-7-generic
Please give the path to kernel build directory with
the KBUILD=<path> argument to make
```

I also have tried uninstalling all ndiswrapper files and re installing. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. I'm trying to get my Netgear WN311T working.

`sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` gives me

```
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, 
it will be ignored in a future release.
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.
```

Comment: See this solution for [Huawei](http://askubuntu.com/a/368669/164718). Something same may be for Netgear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that "make" is failing, because you do not have the linux kernel headers installed.

Install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.7.0-7-generic
```