# Wireless issues on Gateway M-6750

Tags: wireless, gateway

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I can not figure out how to get the wireless working, wired worked fine. I have followed a few instructions on driver downloads but I really do not have a clue what I am doing. I know there is a ton more info you need so just let me know what and how to get it and I will. I am on a Gateway M-6750, I believe it is using the Marvel topdog wireless card (internal). I switched to Ubuntu 13.04 from Windows Vista. Thank you,
John

Here is additional info

`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:b8:e4:a7:e9  
          inet addr:192.168.6.237  Bcast:192.168.6.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:b8ff:fee4:a7e9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10154868 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6843213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14151434429 (14.1 GB)  TX bytes:542801103 (542.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:36886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2707955 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:2707955 (2.7 MB)
```

NetworkManager Tool

```
State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired] --------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:E0:B8:E4:A7:E9

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.6.237
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.6.1

    DNS:             192.168.6.1
    DNS:             64.134.255.2
    DNS:             64.134.255.10
```

`lshw -Cnetwork`

```
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.16
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

    -version        print program version (B.02.16)

format can be
    -html           output hardware tree as HTML
    -xml            output hardware tree as XML
    -short          output hardware paths
    -businfo        output bus information

options can be
    -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
    -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet          don't display status
    -sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
    -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
```

> sudo lshw -C network
>
> > *-network UNCLAIMED
> >
> > > > description: Ethernet controller
> > > >                product: 88W8362e [TopDog] 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless
> > > >                vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
> > > >                physical id: 0
> > > >                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
> > > >                version: 03
> > > >                width: 32 bits
> > > >                clock: 33MHz
> > > >                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
> > > >                configuration: latency=0
> > > >                resources: memory:f6000000-f600ffff memory:f4000000-f400ffff
> >
> > *-network
> >
> > > > description: Ethernet interface
> > > >                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
> > > >                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> > > >                physical id: 0
> > > >                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
> > > >                logical name: eth0
> > > >                version: 01
> > > >                serial: 00:e0:b8:e4:a7:e9
> > > >                size: 100Mbit/s
> > > >                capacity: 100Mbit/s
> > > >                width: 64 bits
> > > >                clock: 33MHz
> > > >                capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
> > > >                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169   driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.6.237 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
> > > >                resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:fa200000-fa200fff memory:c0000000-c001ffff

Answer (score 0):

Check to see which card you have, `lspci -nn`. Device [11ab:2a08] is Gateway 6750.

As I have [read](http://www.mythoughtspot.com/2011/07/30/linux-wireless-driver-for-gateway-6750/) this device needs NDISwrapper, which is a free software driver wrapper that enables the use of Windows XP network device drivers (for devices such as PCI cards, USB modems, and routers) on Linux operating systems.

Make sure you have [ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper), and if you get "ndiswrapper not found", follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132894/how-to-fix-ndiswrapper-not-found). There is also a graphical interface for ndiswrapper that you can use called [ndisgtk](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndisgtk).

Now that you have NDISWrapper installed and working, You should already have the Windows driver extracted into a folder and that you are running these commands from that folder.

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i NetMW14x.inf
sudo ndiswrapper -a 11ab:2a08 netmw14x
sudo ndiswrapper -l
sudo ndiswrapper -m
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Pay attention as you follow, the second command parameter should be the same number as your `lspci` result.

With `-l` you would check which driver is newly installed. and `-m` saves your configuration.

Linux  kernel  modules  can  provide  symbols for other modules to use.
depmod  creates a list of module dependencies by reading each module under /lib/modules/version and determining what symbols it exports and what symbols it needs.

`modprobe` utility is used to add loadable modules to the Linux kernel. You can check how the process have been so far by viewing `dmesg` command result. Especially when you run the last command.

Now that you have your wireless card enabled; Check to see if you network configuration is OK,

1. wireless is shown among your network interfaces, (along with your lan connection),
   (report back commands: iwconfig, ifconfig, nm-tool, lshw -C network)
2. You can scan your wireless network, and see available networks,
3. Your AP has given your interface correct settings (it has IP address and this address is not the same range as your LAN)
4. you can ping your AP,
5. you can browse the net.

Comment: Thank you for the response , I do know that I do not have wireless showing among my network interfaces so I can not see wireless networks and there for can not do any of the other steps.

Comment: I've updated my response to help you through this. you can add the results, and update your question.

Comment: In the command `sudo lshw -C network`, there is a space between C and network, please correct it. If you copy paste from here, you wouldn't make typos.

Comment: Everything looked good till I ran this sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.

Comment: Updated question with  sudo lshw -C network  I apologize but I have not yet learned how to properly post copied text in a nice format. Thank you to the person that fixed my first post.

Comment: BTW the dmesg results all failed

Comment: I know you are just starting to learn, nevertheless, it can be rewarding to help yourself and learn along the way. I suggest you follow these links yourself and report back when you got your NDIS working. To install your [ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper), and to fix ["ndiswrapper not found"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132894/how-to-fix-ndiswrapper-not-found)

Comment: OMG!!!@saeed144, thank you, thank you, thank you. I followed the links, did a LOT of reading and I got it figured out and it's WORKING now.

Comment: Glad to hear to it. It's definitely rewarding. Wherever you found your solution, give feedback, so that people with the same problem can follow what you've done to troubleshoot it. Good luck.

Comment: Well I'm back to where I started. After the latest software update my wifi is not showing up again. I can not figure out how to get it back this time.

Comment: After sudo modprobe ndiswrapper  I get  
ERROR: could not insert 'ndiswrapper': Exec format error