# Ubuntu Wont install packages from CD

Tags: drivers

I'm running a fresh install of 13.04, and I'm trying to install ndiswrapper to make my old pci wireless card work and I've found the correct drivers (according to the ndiswrapper wiki) but when i install them with ndisgtk I get `fatal error ndiswrapper not found`. I tried installing from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/raring/universe/base/ndiswrapper-dkms), but when I use the deb file it asks me to insert the install CD, which I do, but it never seems to pick it up. It says insert disk into `/media/cdrom` to continue, but the path in my file explorer says the CD is located at /media/josh/Ubuntu 13.04 i386.

How can I fix this? I really need ndiswrapper.

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the multiverse and universe repositories are enabled.

[image]

And then, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```

<sup>Source for command:Ubuntu Help</sup>

Comment: i already have done that, ran apt-get update and installed ndisgtk. but the problem now is when i install a driver i get ndiswrapper is not found

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132894/how-to-fix-ndiswrapper-not-found), specially the sixth answer.

Comment: okay, what i had wrong was i had install from cdrom checked. ndiswrapper is installed now, but its still not showing up a wireless connection when i install the driver :\

Comment: @skeetDroid I already suspected that... if it's not showing try `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`, if that don't work, open a new question.

Comment: modprobe ndiswrapper doesnt return an error, but it doesnt do anything either...im not sure how i should word my new question

Comment: Please open the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) run the commands one line at a time: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`nm-tool`
`sudo iwlist scan`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod` post the output at http://pastebin.com/ then post the link here. Thanks